# Frequency of EM waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction, frequency

When light travels in air, all the component frequencies of light travels with the same velocity $v_{air} = 1/\sqrt {\epsilon_0\mu_0}$ (where $\epsilon_0$ is independent of frequency. Then we say that since frequency remains constant,
$k_{air}v_{air}= \omega$

My doubt is, light is made up of many different frequencies, then what frequency is this $\omega$ ?
(Is it the frequency we get after superposition of the rest of the frequencies?)

Comment: The wave vector $k$ also depends on the frequency, so the ratio $\omega/k$ is constant. That means it doesn't matter what value of $\omega$ you choose as long as you choose the corresponding value of $k$.

Comment: Think of sound. What is the frequency of Beethoven's fifth? It is one wave with many frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a wave packet (combination of many frequencies) rather than a monochromatic radiation, one needs to distinguish the [*phase velocity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity), defined as
$$
v_{ph}=\omega/k,
$$
and the [*group velocity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity), defined as
$$
v_g =\frac{\partial \omega(k)}{\partial k}.
$$
The former characterizes the relation between the frequency and the wave vector, whereas the latter describes propagation of the wave packet as a whole.

For the light in vacuum these two velocities are equal (since $\omega=ck$), which means that vacuum is a *dispersionless medium*, and the packet of electromagnetic waves propagates undistorted. In [dispersive media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)) this is not the case.

Comment: So when we talk about light, we talk about the wave packets. Also, when we have a short pulse, why does it flatten out after some time? (Even though it does not pass through any medium)

Comment: *Light* can mean many things - we do not necessarily talk about wave packets when we talk about light. Perhaps, you could add more details about the situation that you are describing in your question. Also - what do you mean when you say that a pulse "flattens"? Btw, note that I am talking about waves in vacuum - it might be different in the air, and your assumption that air is dispersionless is not always correct.